# How to POST data form as JSON using API in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I create a form using GET from API. After I've created that form, I want to POST the form data back to the API, encoded as JSON. How do I do that?

I have this simple text field:

```
<template v-if="questions.question_type == 1">
 <div class="title-1"><b>{{questions.question_title}} -</b> {{questions.question_desc}}
 </div>
 <v-text-field required :v-model="questions.question_tag" color="green darken-1" clearable></v-text-field>
</template>
```

How do I validate and POST the data?

Comment: The actual POST doesn't seem to be related to vue or vuetify but javascript in general. For the validation you need to be a little more specific, for example: What kind of validation do you want to do? It would really help if you added your <script> </script> block too

Comment: ok I want to POST data first

Comment: Sidenote: "According to the HTML5 specification, the <b> tag should be used as a LAST resort when no other tag is more appropriate." (w3schools) Not adopting these as a habit, even in draft code, might be a worthwhile idea.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't know what you're using to call your API I just assume you're using Axios.

Easiest would be to create a method and in that method you create a POST.

```
data() {
  return {
    questions: {
      question_tag: "" // Your value in your v-text-field
    }
  }
},
methods: {
  sendData() {
    axios.post('https://yourServer/your/api/endpoint', {
      questionTags: this.questions.question_tag
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }
}
```

To handle validation we need more information on what you're trying to validate. Empty textboxes? Only specific inputs such as numbers? Check for a maximum character count?

Comment: Yes, I use Axios. Thanks. But my form get data by API too, so how to select question with answer together?

Comment: I'm really sorry but I don't understand what you're asking of. Can you maybe provide a codesandbox or codepen as an example?

Comment: In line 14 you set this.survey, but survey was never defined in the data(). I suggest you check out more simple vue examples before diving into APIs. Adressing everything in the codepen would be too much for a comment here, sorry